In Next.js, client js taken from an iframe does not work
The requirement was to embed the statically generated HTML in Next.js into the parent site, and we wanted to dynamically switch the Next HTML internally in the outermost layer.
To see how it works, I tried the following implementation, which first loads Next's SG file over an iframe and transfers it to a new separate div element.
'use client';

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export default function Parent() {
  const iframeRef = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);
  const targetRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<NodeListOf<ChildNode>>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const iframeDocumentBody = iframeRef.current?.contentWindow?.document?.body;

    if (!iframeDocumentBody) return;

    const childNodes = iframeDocumentBody.cloneNode(true).childNodes;


    if (!hasCopied.current) {
      setNodes(childNodes);
      iframeRef.current.remove();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const targetDiv = targetRef.current;
    nodes?.forEach((node) => {
      targetDiv?.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
    });
  }, [nodes]);

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={targetRef} id="target" /> // target div to move

      <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        src="/ssg/child.html" // generated SG HTML
      />
    </>
  );
}

The output of the page at this time is as follows:
<!-- parent.html -->
<html lang="en">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div id="target">
      <!-- child.html body -->
      <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-46d202d2d09b00c3.js" async=""></script>
      <script>...</script>
      <script>...</script>
      <next-route-announcer style="position: absolute;"></next-route-announcer>
      <div>...</div> // SG content(not working click event or and so on)
      ...
    </div>
    <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?v=1727746810006" async=""></script>
    <script>...</script>
  </body>

At first glance it looks good, but the js on the staticized page that was working in the iframe does not work in the new location, even though the script tag has also been moved.
Why is it not working and how can I make it work or is it impossible?
